# How to define range of values of a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, axis, scaling, currency-exchange-rates

First of all, sorry for any mistakes regarding my post, I'm new to this site.

I´m getting started with R now and I´m trying to do some analysis with time series data.
So, I got a times series at hand and already loaded it into R. 
I can also plot this times series and add labels to the axes and so on. So far so good.

My problem: When I plot the time series, R would set the range of values on the y-axis to the interval of [0:170] approximately. 
This is somehow strange, since the times series contains the daily EUR/USD exchange rates for this year. That means the values are in a range of about 1.05 to 1.2.

[image]

The relative values are correct. 
If the plot shows a maximum around day 40, the corresponding value in the data set appears to be a maximum.
But it is around 1.4 and not 170.

I hope one can understand my problem. 
I would like to have the y-axis on a scale from 1 to 1.2 for example.
The `ylim=c(1, 1.2)` command will scale the axis to that range but not the values. 
It just ignores them.

Does anyone know how to adjust that? 
I´d really appreciate it.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

Thanks a lot for the input so far.
The "critical code" is the following:

```
> FRB <- read.csv("FRB_H10.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> attach(FRB)
> str(FRB)
'data.frame':   212 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date: Factor w/ 212 levels "2015-01-01","2015-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8 9 10 ...
 $ Rate: Factor w/ 180 levels "1.0524","1.0575",..: 180 179 177 178 174 173 175 176 171 172 ...
> plot.ts(Rate)
```

The result of this last plot is the one shown above.

Changing the variable to numeric yields this:

```
> as.numeric(Rate)
  [1] 180 179 177 178 174 173 175 176 171 172 170 166 180 167 169 160 123 128 150 140 132 128 138 165
 [25] 161 163 136 134 134 129 159 158 180 156 140 155 151 142 131 148 104 100  96 104  65  53  27  24
 [49]  13   3   8   1   2   7  10   9  21  42  36  50  39  33  23  15  19  29  51  54  26  23  11   6
 [73]   4  12   5  16  20  18  17  14  22  30  34  49  92  89  98  83  92 141 125 110  81 109 151 149
 [97] 162 143  85  69  77  61 180  30  32  38  52  37  78 127 120  73 105 126 131 106 122 119 107 112
[121] 157 137 152  96  93  99  87  94  86  70  71 180  67  43  66  58  84  57  55  47  35  25  26  41
[145]  31  48  48  75  63  59  38  60  46  44  28  40  45  52  62 101  82  74  68  60  64 102 144 168
[169] 159 154 108  91  98 118 111  72  76 180  95  90 117 139 131 116 130 133 145 103  79  88 115  97
[193] 106 113  89 102 121 102 119 114 124 148 180 153 164 161 147 135 146 141  80  56
```

So, it remains unchanged. This is very strange. The data excerpt shows that "Rate" takes on values between 1.1 and 1.5 approximately, so really not the values that are shown above. :/

The data set can be found under this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndxstdl1aae5glt/FRB_H10.csv?dl=0

It should be alright. I got it from the data base from the Federal Reserve System, so quite a decent source.

(Had to remove the link to the data excerpt because my reputation only allows for 2 links to be posted at a time. But the entire data set should be even better, I guess.

Comment: perhaps your currency column is a factor right now. try the str() function to have a look at your data. Maybe it'll be as simple as changing your values to numeric

Comment: A question to SO should have complete minimal self contained code including all inputs, library statements, etc. so readers can copy and paste it into an R session to reproduce the result on their own machine.  These 3 links contain more on how to ask questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I´ve just edited the question and included the code. :)

Comment: The discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) might be relevant to your problem as `as.numeric` does not do what you think it should do.

Answer (score 1):

@BlankUsername

Thanks very much for the link. I got it working now using this code:

```
FRB <- read.csv("FRB_H10.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> attach(FRB)
> as.numeric(paste(Rate))
  [1]     NA 1.2015 1.1918 1.1936 1.1820 1.1811 1.1830 1.1832 1.1779 1.1806 1.1598 1.1517     NA
 [14] 1.1559 1.1584 1.1414 1.1279 1.1290 1.1370 1.1342 1.1308 1.1290 1.1337 1.1462 1.1418 1.1432
 [27] 1.1330 1.1316 1.1316 1.1300 1.1410 1.1408     NA 1.1395 1.1342 1.1392 1.1372 1.1346 1.1307
 [40] 1.1363 1.1212 1.1197 1.1190 1.1212 1.1070 1.1006 1.0855 1.0846 1.0707 1.0576 1.0615 1.0524
 [53] 1.0575 1.0605 1.0643 1.0621 1.0792 1.0928 1.0908 1.0986 1.0919 1.0891 1.0818 1.0741 1.0768
 [66] 1.0874 1.0990 1.1008 1.0850 1.0818 1.0671 1.0598 1.0582 1.0672 1.0596 1.0742 1.0780 1.0763
 [79] 1.0758 1.0729 1.0803 1.0876 1.0892 1.0979 1.1174 1.1162 1.1194 1.1145 1.1174 1.1345 1.1283
 [92] 1.1241 1.1142 1.1240 1.1372 1.1368 1.1428 1.1354 1.1151 1.1079 1.1126 1.1033     NA 1.0876
[105] 1.0888 1.0914 1.0994 1.0913 1.1130 1.1285 1.1271 1.1108 1.1232 1.1284 1.1307 1.1236 1.1278
[118] 1.1266 1.1238 1.1244 1.1404 1.1335 1.1378 1.1190 1.1178 1.1196 1.1156 1.1180 1.1154 1.1084
[131] 1.1090     NA 1.1076 1.0952 1.1072 1.1025 1.1150 1.1020 1.1015 1.0965 1.0898 1.0848 1.0850
[144] 1.0927 1.0884 1.0976 1.0976 1.1112 1.1055 1.1026 1.0914 1.1028 1.0962 1.0953 1.0868 1.0922
[157] 1.0958 1.0994 1.1042 1.1198 1.1144 1.1110 1.1078 1.1028 1.1061 1.1200 1.1356 1.1580 1.1410
[170] 1.1390 1.1239 1.1172 1.1194 1.1263 1.1242 1.1104 1.1117     NA 1.1182 1.1165 1.1262 1.1338
[183] 1.1307 1.1260 1.1304 1.1312 1.1358 1.1204 1.1133 1.1160 1.1252 1.1192 1.1236 1.1246 1.1162
[196] 1.1200 1.1276 1.1200 1.1266 1.1249 1.1282 1.1363     NA 1.1382 1.1437 1.1418 1.1360 1.1320
[209] 1.1359 1.1345 1.1140 1.1016
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> Rate <- cbind(paste(Rate))
> plot(Rate)
Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
> plot.ts(Rate, ylab="EUR/USD")
```

Despite the warning message, I get the following output (shown below). Like I intended to plot it.

[image]

Nevertheless, I do not really understand why it works the way it did. Why I have to use the `paste()` command and what it does exactly. I get the basic idea of what the classes do, but am very new to this whole world of R.

One thing I came to realize already is that R is such a powerful program. And yet confusing if you are a beginner. :D

Comment: Do the NAs persist when you use `as.numeric(levels(Rate))[Rate]`? Would be nice if that can be sorted out as well so you have a fully functioning code.

Comment: Yes, still "NAs introduced by coercion". What does NA mean, by the way?

Comment: NA is for not available, if I´m not mistaken? Why does R introduce those? I mean there have been some NAs in the data set from the beginning. But obviously, R created some more.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this happens. Another thing you can try is to include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `read.csv` command. That should prevent R from loading the data as factors in the first place.

Comment: `stringsAsFactors = False` works fine, as well. It´s even easier to do it this way and load the data as numeric from the get-go.
The output is, of course, the same as shown above. The scale on the y-axis is correct.